# Checking who issued a server mute on another user

Tags: javascript, discord

Does anyone know if it's possible to track who has issued server mutes on other users on discord? I couldn't find anything mentioning this in the documentation, but I would like to be able to log these kinds of events. The logging system for Discord in general seems to be lacking as well.

Comment: I doubt you can, unless you are the user that issued the mute action.

Comment: @plalx That is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Only the audit logs have access to that unless its issued via a command, but if its done by right clicking and then ticking "Server Mute" then no, its not possible.